# How to catch all upper cases in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a string like `"TransfCoolingFanG1" I want to have the output: "TCFG1".
How I build a javascript function for this purpose?

Comment: `if (character === character.toUpperCase())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or, another approach (replace all EXCEPT uppercase letters and numbers):

```
str="TransfCo^^^oli*****ngFanG1";
str=str.replace(/[^A-Z0-9]/g,'');
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method and replace all small letters.

```js
console.log(
  "TransfCoolingFanG1".replace(/[a-z]+/g, '')
)
```

---

**UPDATE :** If you want to remove all character except capital case or digit then use [negated character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) with regex.

```js
console.log(
  "TransfCoolingFanG1".replace(/[^A-Z\d]+/g, '')
)
```

Comment: That's creative

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = "TransfCoolingFanG1";
var res = "";
var len = str.length;
for (var i = 0; i < len ; i++) 
    if (str[i] === str[i].toUpperCase()) 
      res = res + str[i];
window.alert(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe more native :

```
var yourString = "TransfCoolingFanG1";
var upString= "";
for (var i = 0; i < yourString.length;i++){
        if (isUpperCase(yourString.charAt(i)));{ 
            upString +=yourString.charAt(i);       
        }
 }
```

window.alert(upString);

Answer (score 1):

EcmaScript 6 approach

```
inputString => inputString.split('').filter(x => x === x.toUpperCase()).join('')
```

So what happens here in this arrow function:

1. Once we have *inputString*, we get an array of characters from it by applying function *split* with empty string '' separator
2. Once we have array of characters, we want to find all uppercase letters.
3. Apply *filter* function with an argument of predicate which tests each element of array for being uppercased or not. In case character does not equal it's uppercase variant, predicate returns false and filter erases element from array.
4. Last step is just collecting new string from array of filtered characters by *joining* it with empty string '' separator